# Can I make a Access 2010 web database and pulish it on to Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: web, app

I'm a little limited to in the use of Sharepoint designer on our new SP2013. In order to allow some more flexibility I would like to develop an Access 2010 web app and publish it to Sharepoint 2013 enterprise (on location server version).
Is this possible and where can I find some help/samples ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can publish Access 2010 Web Databases to SharePoint 2013 as long as an Access Services 2010 service application has been configured, see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748653.aspx